# Short syntax for if (!obj.prop) obj.prop = val

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Is there any short syntax or trick to write such as in code below?

```
if (!obj.prop) {
    obj.prop = value;
}
```

Comment: You can make it one line as well: `if (!obj.prop) obj.prop = value;` You can't avoid writing `obj.prop` twice if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe

```
obj.prop = obj.prop || value;
```

but be aware that if `obj.prop` is a falsy value, it will get set to `value`.

Perhaps you want to test to see if the property is defined for `obj`

```
if (obj.prop === undefined) obj.prop = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
obj.prop = obj.prop || value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  obj.prop = obj.prop? obj.prop : value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a function, and then you would need to write this `if` once, and call the function each time you need this code.

Comment: Could you write an example function to demonstrate?

Comment: @Russ: For example, if it's always the same 'prop', then you can do: `function f(obj) {if (!obj.prop) obj.prop = value;}`